# How do you calculate the first and third quartile of a sorted array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am writing a program that calculates the median, first quartile, and third quartile, of a sorted array. If I already know what the median is, how could I calculate the first and third quartile of that array?

For instance if I had these variables:

```
int nums[1000] = {};
int amount;
```

How would I calculate the first and third quartile of the nums array?

Comment: How do you get the median? The quartiles should be similar.

Comment: But how would I do that, i'm confused.

Comment: What have you tried? Please post some code, and if you have the median, the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile) shows you how to get your answer.

Comment: I know how to find the quartiles on a piece of paper just not how to do it in code.

Comment: The median divides the array into two pieces. Just find the median of each piece.

Answer (score 1):

If the array is sorted,
First quartile is `nums[250]`
Third quartiles is `nums[750]`